# I need to randomly assign placement of stimuli when sequentially presenting photos

Tags: psychopy

I am programming a psychology experiment. I'm trying to present 4 photo stimuli sequentially with blank ITS screens between. I need them to vary where they appear on the screen anywhere in a circle around [0,0]. I also need the position to be random. I have most of the code done, I just don't have the random placement. Does anyone know what kind of function I would use to create this randomization of placement?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please have a read of the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  article in the Help Center for tips to improve your changes of getting answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be on a circle of a fixed distance you only need one random number: the angle between 0 and 360. You can use that to figure out the X's and Y's for placing your objects on the screen. x = r × cos( θ ) and y = r × sin( θ ).

To get a random number import the random library and choose a number uniformly between 0 and 360 (if working in degrees and 0 and 2*pi if working in radians).

```
import random as r
r.uniform(0,360)
```

Do watch your units, and be aware that psychopy has convenience functions for these conversions in [psychopy.misc](http://www.psychopy.org/api/misc.html)